# python:AttributeError: 'RenderSettings' objects has no attribute 'alpha_mode' blender quit

Tags: python, ubuntu, blender, bpy

I tried to run the old python code that rendered images using bpy,then I got this error:

> AttributeError: 'RenderSettings' objects has no attribute 'alpha_mode'
> blender quit

I tried to install the oldest version of bpy, but the result did not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that since Blender has changed a lot since version 2.8 [blender version](https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/), the version of Blender installed on the OS needs to be changed to 2.7, so I first uninstalled the previously installed Blender, then installed Blender 2.79 [download links](https://download.blender.org/release/).